# ZIndex within a DockPanel

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, dockpanel

I have a DockPanel as the root element for my window.

I have another DockPanel that is essentially a menu bar which is set to be docked to the Top of the root-element-DockPanel.

I would like to have an image docked to the top of the root-element-DockPanel that floats over the menu-bar-DockPanel.

For example:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="RootDockPanel">
  <Image Souce="/MyProject;component/Images/imageName.jpg" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Panel.ZIndex="3" />
  <DockPanel x:Name="MenuDockPanel" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Panel.ZIndex="0">
    <!-- content -->
  </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

I have tried setting the Panel.ZIndex of the Image to something higher than the Panel.ZIndex of the menu-bar-DockPanel but this doesn't work.

Since the ZIndex is proving to be useless, I'm not sure how to accomplish this and I'm looking for your input.

Thanks for your help!

-Frinny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend simply ditching the DockPanel control and using Grid instead. In my experience, DockPanel is a poorly-designed control and is the most useless of all the panel controls in WPF.

Comment: As much as I hated this answer when I asked the question originally; I found that ditching the DockPanel and using a Grid instead fixed the issue and has been my approach ever since. So yeah, it didn't answer my question on how to fix the DockPanel; but it did help me overall.

Answer (score 2):

`DockPanel.ZIndex` works for me.

Here's an example to help (it may not compile, I just wrote it from memory to illustrate the concept):

```
<DockPanel>
    <Label 
        Background="Yellow" 
        Content="Foo" 
        DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
        DockPanel.ZIndex="1"
        />
    <Label 
        Background="Green" 
        Content="Bar" 
        DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
        DockPanel.ZIndex="0" 
        />
</DockPanel>
```